# How to change Unicode of a variable in PowerShell

Tags: git, variables, powershell, unicode

I am trying to store a value of a Git command into a variable. The command results in a name that contains [a Danish alphabet character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98). When I give that Git command only, on the prompt I get the correct result. As shown below:

#

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> git config user.name

John Møller

#

But when I store the result of this command into a variable and then display that variable I get a different result. what am I doing wrong? Has it something to do with Unicode [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)? Can I use `Get-Content -encoding utf8` to change the Unicode setting of a variable? I know Get-Content work with files.

#

```
     PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $nameingit = git config user.name
     PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $nameingit
     John M├©ller
```

#

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to reproduce your issue and believe it's related to the font used for PowerShell. When I first pasted "John Møller" into my PowerShell window, it turned into "John Moller". I changed my font to Consolas, and it stayed "John Møller".

Just right click on the title bar, go to Properties, Font, and change your font. Your fonts are probably different than mine, but try a few out and see if it helps.

One thing to note: You'll need to re-test for every font change. I noticed that once I changed the font that made the "ø" an "o", it stayed that way even after changing to a font that did support "ø".

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have resolved the issue. But I had to create a text file. Actually, I have to transfer the value to an HTML file where it shows the wrong alphabet. 
But I have resolved it by creating a temporary file, writing the value into that file and then reading back that file into a variable:

```
git config user.name | set-content encoding eom <file name>
$variable = get-content -encoding utf8 <file name>
```

Now I get the correct value in $variable which I further write into an HTML file.